# Main Content area not aligning

Tags: html, css

This is my first time coding a vertical nav menu on a website, I am not sure how to align the main content div so that its at the top. Any other recommendations welcome.

I cannot seem to get my css formatted correctly here:
[CSS](http://www.dev.noo.co.nz/House/includes/css/style.css)

[Main View](http://www.dev.noo.co.nz/House/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the float declaration from your #content style.

Comment: As an aside, may I suggest looking at [@stubbornella's](http://twitter.com/stubbornella) Nicole Sullivan's OOCSS talks and presentations? They'd really help your development and layout no end! http://www.slideshare.net/stubbornella/our-best-practices-are-killing-us